# Salesforce 1 shows edit button in PC Browsers not in mobile browsers

Tags: chatter, mobile, salesforce1-app

Recently I wanted to show the custom object records in mobile browsers using Salesforce 1. The purpose is to make the record editable for users.  Edit buttons are opening if I open Salesforce 1 through PC browsers, but **mobile browsers are not displaying the edit buttton**.

I could find no documentation for this behaviour. Also as Salesforce is intended for mobile then the edit buttons are essential. I am not sure any setting mismatch from my end. Any suggestion or Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Shebin, not quite sure if you mean that you are using mobile browsers to see your org or Salesforce 1 app. I'm using Salesforce 1 app in my mobile and I'm able to see edit button. The user that is logged in my mobile app has edit permission on the custom object, might be the one that you are using has only read only access to the records?

A workaround, meanwhile, could be to use a Publisher action. A publisher action "Update" type linked to your custom object could be a temporary solution. ( or might be not only temporary because in the publisher action you will be able to control which fields you show to the user to be updated :) ) 
Hope it helps.

Comment: i am using salesforcew 1 using mobile browser using the url https://domain/one/one.app. The logged in user had edit permissions  also

Comment: There should not be a difference for the Edit buttons. You are sure it was the same user?

Comment: Good point @KrisGray I'm using the same user :)

Comment: Do you have a bug filled? I'll need to dig in probably to see what's up.

Comment: What type of entity is not showing the button? Is it a simple Account? or something fancy?